# Erasing iPhone and backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I've got iPhone 4S and I wanna sell it...I have backed up contacts on http://icloud.com ...Does contacts remain on http://icloud.com after reseting all iPhone settings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the contacts remain in iCloud. However, once you reset the iPhone to factory settings, the iPhone is no longer logged in to your iCloud account which means that there are no contacts appearing on the iPhone whatsoever.

You can further log in to your iCloud account on your computer via a web browser (icloud.com) and erase the contacts from there if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the contacts you have backed up to iCloud will remain after using the “Erase all the content and settings” feature on your iPhone.

To fully erase an iPhone to avoid important data being recovered for illegal usage, see the guide:
[5 Methods to Erase iPhone Completely and Securely](http://www.iphonebackup-extractor.com/articles/how-to-erase-iphone/)

If you want to delete the contacts in your iCloud account, see the “Delete backups and turn off Backup for your device” section in this guide:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4847